# Python Vimeo Api Error 401 Unauthorized - Invalid signature - The oauth_signature passed was not valid

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0

```
d = {'client_id': '***', 'client_secret': '***', 'grant_type': 'authorization_code','redirect_uri': 'http://192.168.2.135:8000/vimeo/response/',
'response_type': 'code'}
req = oauth2.Request(method='GET',url="https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize",parameters=d)
consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key = '***',secret="***")
client = oauth2.Client(consumer)
request_token_url = "http://vimeo.com/oauth/access_token"
resp,content = client.request(request_token_url,"GET")
```

Comment: Please add a useful error description, and the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: Actually i got error 401 Unauthorized - Invalid signature - The oauth_signature passed was not valid. and i am new to oauth

Comment: May i know how to pass oauth_signature

Comment: I think the error is because of Proxy through which the request is going , Try disabling the proxy and try once again, It might be a restriction in your office PC, try doing it without using any proxy

Comment: Sorry i did not get can u explain in detail